# SMTP mail error 452 4.3.1 Insufficient system storage

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I have a server which uses Postfix as the mail system. The issue I am having is I am not able to send or recieve email. If I send an email I get an instant reply from the server which says:

```
Subject:    test
Sent:   16/05/2011 19:08

The following recipient(s) could not be reached:

'myemail@mydomain.com' on 16/05/2011 19:08
452 4.3.1 Insufficient system storage
```

I have check the following:

Disk space, there are gigabytes of free space on all partitions.
Mailbox quotas, there are no quota,s set on any mailbox.

I cleared all the mail logs and rebooted the server but I still cannot send email. does anyone have any pointers for me to look at next.

I have looked at the `main.cf` file and here are the results:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:110
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
myhostname = mydomain.com
message_size_limit = 2048000000
```

Comment: What is the domain of your server and what is the domain of the receiving server? Are you sure it is not the external server returning the error? What OS does the server use - are you sure it is not SELinux related. Please post log file extracts.

Answer (score 4):

Set your message_size_limit to a sane value and you will be fine.

With the current value you will need about 3Gb of free space to receive mails.
If you want to set it to a really big number set it to:

```
message_size_limit = 104857600
```

This allows about 100Mb size (which no one will send you anyways as the remote limit will be smaller).

Answer (score 2):

From a forum post i found...

> Do you have either message_size_limit
>   or queue_minfree set?
>
> You probably don't need queue_minfree
>   set, and you will get the error you
>   indicated if you don't have at least
>   1.5X the value of message_size_limit free (it could have a large value set
>   by mistake)

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this issue. In the `main.cf` file set:

```
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
```

Zero means it will take max limit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of the directories APT is using as cache. If it's storing too much, clear it (with root Privilege)  using

```
rm -r /var/cache/apt/*.*
```

Comment: Better use `apt-get autoclean` and it's equivalents in aptitude.

Comment: If your mail server is important to you, it would not use the same partition as Apt anyway.

Comment: @tripleee Meaning not the same 'vmail' partition/mount-point. In other words, use a different drive/mount point for your mailboxes/vmail directory. ( /root, Apt, Postfix and applications still reside on primary drive/mount.)