# Postfix SMTP server: errors from

Tags: postfix

I'm running the Postfix mail server ru000397.widhost.net. I'm getting some of these messages in postmaster@ru000397.widhost.net.

The mail service is working and, obviously, there is much free space on all drivers.

```
Transcript of session follows.

 Out: 220 ru000397.widhost.net ESMTP Postfix
 In:  EHLO m145.gem.godaddy.com
 Out: 250-ru000397.widhost.net
 Out: 250-PIPELINING
 Out: 250-SIZE 52428800
 Out: 250-ETRN
 Out: 250-STARTTLS
 Out: 250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
 Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 Out: 250-8BITMIME
 Out: 250 DSN
 In:  MAIL FROM:<mailman@m145.gem.godaddy.com> BODY=8BITMIME
 Out: 452 4.3.1 Insufficient system storage
 In:  RCPT TO:<info@gilperformance.it>
 Out: 503 5.5.1 Error: need MAIL command
 In:  DATA
 Out: 503 5.5.1 Error: need RCPT command
 In:  QUIT
 Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye


For other details, see the local mail logfile
```

main.cf: http://pastebin.com/RCBx891e
master.cf: http://pastebin.com/1HMyXzuT

Here is my df outputs:

```
[root@ru000397 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        22G   20G  1.5G  94% /
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb        2.7T  1.7T  867G  67% /usr/local/psa

[root@ru000397 ~]# df -i
Filesystem        Inodes    IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        1455328   242748   1212580   17% /
tmpfs            2035051        2   2035049    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb       181141504 11000662 170140842    7% /usr/local/psa
```

Here is my message_size_limit:

```
[root@ru000397 ~]# postconf -n|grep message_size_limit
message_size_limit = 52428800
```

Comment: Include your postfix configuration.

Comment: updated question

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/270294/smtp-mail-error-452-4-3-1-insufficient-system-storage

Comment: @Rudolph The two answers provided there seem not to apply here.

Comment: My max message size is 50MB, and I have more than 1.5X free space on all partitions. So that answer does not apply too.

Comment: Can  you post full maillog entry when rejection happened?

Comment: solved. effectively space was missing on a partition in the moment I got the error, but there was free space when I checked it. Don't know why the space is bouncing up and down, but the problem effectively was the disk full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have enough free disk space for /var? How does your `df -h` and `df -i` look like? You most likely do not actually have enough space or have run out of inodes.

Comment: Sure. Updated question with df outputs.

Comment: How about your master.cf? Also, do you have quotas enabled on that file system?

Comment: update question with master.cf

Comment: solved. effectively space was missing on a partition in the moment I got the error, but there was free space when I checked it. Don't know why the space is bouncing up and down, but the problem effectively was the disk full.

Answer (score -2):

Run `postconf -n` to print out your postfix configuration and locate the value for `message_size_limit`.

Check the amount of space left in `/var/spool/postfix` by running:

```
du -sh /var/spool/postfix
```

Comment: `postconf message_size_limit` is easier, no need to search for the value. `du` gives the used disk space, not the space left.

Comment: [root@ru000397 ~]# du -sh /var/spool/postfix
12M     /var/spool/postfix